# Pythonic way to concatenate regex objects

Tags: python, regex

I have python regex objects - say, re_first and re_second - I would like to concatenate.

```
import re
FLAGS_TO_USE = re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE
re_first = re.compile( r"""abc #Some comments here """, FLAGS_TO_USE )
re_second = re.compile( r"""def #More comments here """, FLAGS_TO_USE )
```

I want one regex expression that matches either one of the above regex expressions. So far, I have

```
pattern_combined = re_first.pattern + '|' + re_second.pattern
re_combined = re.compile( pattern_combined, FLAGS_TO_USE )
```

This doesn't scale very well the more python objects. I end up with something looking like:

```
pattern_combined = '|'.join( [ first.pattern, second.pattern, third.pattern, etc ] )
```

The point is that the list to concatenate can be very long. Any ideas how to avoid this mess?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to compile them individually before concatenating?

Comment: @1_CR That's because that's how they are given; they are inputs. To get the string patterns individually, I would have to do even more gruesome acrobatics.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think you will find a solution that doesn't involve creating a list with the regex objects first. I would do it this way:

```
# create patterns here...
re_first = re.compile(...)
re_second = re.compile(...)
re_third = re.compile(...)

# create a list with them
regexes = [re_first, re_second, re_third]

# create the combined one
pattern_combined = '|'.join(x.pattern for x in regexes)
```

Of course, you can also do the opposite: Combine the patterns and then compile, like this:

```
pattern1 = r'pattern-1'
pattern2 = r'pattern-2'
pattern3 = r'pattern-3'

patterns = [pattern1, pattern2, pattern3]

compiled_combined = re.compile('|'.join(x for x in patterns), FLAGS_TO_USE)
```

Comment: You can't join patterns that contain comments with `|`, you must use `\n|`.

Comment: Thanks. The first solution is more suitable for my purpose.

Comment: what if some of the sub-patterns include the `|` operator inside them? doesn't it make problem this way? for example consider the case where `pattern1=r'[a-z]|[0-9]'

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi Why would it be a problem? If both `[a-z]` and `[0-9]` are valid inputs for pattern 1 and your full patterns is `pattern1|pattern2|pattern3` then substituting pattern1 with `[a-z]|[0-9]` is totally valid: `[a-z]|[0-9]|pattern2|pattern3`. And for any or that's not on a global level, you need groups anyway

Comment: @h345k34cr You're right, it completely makes sense now. I don't know what I was thinking back then.

Answer (score 5):

Toss them on a list, and then

```
'|'.join(your_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also directly concatenate r strings, for example:

```py
prep_re = r"\b" + r"\b|\b".join(prepositions) + r"\b"
re.findall(prep_re, paragraph, re.IGNORECASE)
```