# Using a list as an argument for a regular expression in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am building regular expressions to find dates in my text. I have created lists for the month name, day, and specials characters that are part of a date.

```
dict_month_name =['january','february','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december']

dict_day =['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']

dict_special_char = ['-', '/', '.', ',' ,'',' ']
```

I have also compiled them as shown below.

```
month_name = re.compile('|'.join(dict_month_name))

day = re.compile('|'.join(dict_day))

special_char = re.compile('|'.join(dict_special_char))
```

Now, in my regular expression shown below, I want to use different variations of the lists I created earlier. For e.g. to search for dates like - Monday, January 2017 the regex would be -

```
regexp1 = re.findall('.*?^(day+,\s,month_name+\s[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$.*', text)
```

However, the regex is not returning any output. I need to solve this using regex and not the datetime module. Is there a way I can include my list inside the regular expression as shown above ?

Comment: `regexp1` is not using any of the precompiled regexes, and is literally searching for `'day'` and `'month_name'` in `text`.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to directly combine compiled regexes. Closest I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102814/pythonic-way-to-concatenate-regex-objects).

Comment: @DeepSpace Is there a way I can tell the re.findall function to read "day" and "month_name" as a list  and not text to search for a pattern as you mentioned?

Comment: thanks for the advice. I have reviewed my questions and accepted answers as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine the regex the following way:

```
import re
dict_month_name =['january','february','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december']
dict_day =['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
dict_special_char = ['-', '/', '.', ',' ,'',' ']

s = 'For e.g. to search for dates like - Monday, January 2017 the regex would be'
rx = r"\b(?:{day})[{special}]\s+(?:{month_name})\s+[0-9]{{4}}\b".format(
    day="|".join(dict_day), 
    special="".join([re.escape(x) for x in dict_special_char]), 
    month_name="|".join(dict_month_name))

print(re.findall(rx, s, re.I)) # => ['Monday, January 2017']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mB39Fh).

In this example, the regex will be

```
\b(?:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)[\-\/\.\,\ ]\s+(?:january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\s+[0-9]{4}\b
```

You see that the patterns are now part of a bigger pattern. `re.I` enables case insensitive matching.

Also note that special chars should be escaped with `[re.escape(x) for x in dict_special_char]` in order to get matched as literal chars.

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to work. One more thing though. I have many variations within my date data. Do I need to write a regex for each unique format or is there a more efficient way to solve this using a regex dictionary method?

Comment: @user8929822 I think you need to handle them with their respective patterns, but you may use `|` to add alternatives to one single regex.