# Make Python RegEx More Concise

Tags: python, regex

I'm still quite unfamiliar with Python, albeit I have quite a bit of experience with JavaScript, so it's really only the idiosyncrasies of Python that I need to work on. Considering that, and the fact that I know there are some subtle differences between JS RegEx and Python RegEx, I have a question about a Python RegEx statement. Is there any way to make the following statement more concise?

**The Whole Regular Expression**

```
^https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/[a-z]+-?[a-z]+\?project_type=[a-z]+&project_timing=[a-z]+_?[a-z]+&tags=&sort=trending$
```

`^https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/[a-z]+-?[a-z]+\?project_type=[a-z]+&project_timing=[a-z]+_?[a-z]+&tags=&sort=trending$`

**Breakdown of the Whole Regular Expression**

I'll break this down further for you. The URL address will always begin with *`^https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/`* and always end with *`&tags=&sort=trending$`*, so no need to worry about this, but...

`[a-z]+-?[a-z]+\?project_type=[a-z]+&project_timing=[a-z]+_?[a-z]+`

...is the specific part of the regular expression that matters, which can be broken down even further.

**URL Structure and Possible Formats of Dynamic Values**

1. `^https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/`
2. `word` or `dash-separated` or `separated-by-dashes` or `words-separated-by-dashes`
3. `?project_type=`
4. `word`
5. `&project_timing=`
6. `word` or `additional_word`
7. `&tags=&sort=trending$`

Steps `1.`, `3.`, `5.`, and `7.` can be ignored altogether, which leaves us with...

**The Only Dynamic Values**

2. `word` or `dash-separated` or `separated-by-dashes` or `words-separated-by-dashes`

6. `word` or `additional_word`

*It may be my own ignorance or inexperience, but the regular expression I've devised seems clunky so to speak.* **Is there any way to improve this regular expression?!**

Comment: Parsing URLs in Python is easier with [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i'm not trying to parse the url. i need a regex for an object in a particular framework

Comment: You could compile each piece of the regex separately so they're more manageable, and then join them together as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102814/pythonic-way-to-concatenate-regex-objects

Comment: @divibisan interesting!

Comment: @davedwards i'm not looking to concatenate a regex object... that was simply somebody's suggestion

Comment: @Anthony, great, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @davedwards np!

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `[a-z]+-?[a-z]+` can simply be replaced with `[\-\w]+` or `[a-z\-]+` if you want to restrict it to just lower case alpha characters and `-`, and again, `[a-z]+_?[a-z]+` can be replaced with `[a-z_]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having any sample URLs to test with, the simplest solution I could find is this:

`^https:\/\/www.indiegogo.com\/explore\/[a-z\-?_=]+&project_timing=[a-z_]+&tags=&sort=trending$`

So here's a breakdown of what I did differently:

- Instead of `[a-z]+-?[a-z]+\?project_type=[a-z]+`, I simplified it with `[a-z\-?_=]+`
- Instead of `[a-z]+_?[a-z]+` I used `[a-z_]+`

The only issue I saw was that you aren't taking full advantage of your character classes. If you would like to provide a few sample URLs I'd be able to fix any issues you might run into. [But as far as I can tell, it does what you need it to.](https://regex101.com/r/6RckWL/15)

You can also use `^https:\/\/www.indiegogo.com\/explore\/[\w\-]+&project_timing=[\w]+&tags=&sort=trending$` if you **really** want to simplify, but that might not be restrictive enough.

Comment: god, i keep writing messages to you and then editing my question and it keeps erasing my messages. the first bit in your initial comment (i.e. using `\w`, etc) wouldn't have worked since it would've matched much more than just alphabet characters, but it got me thinking, and, yeah, `2. [a-z-]+` and `6. [a-z_]` are definitely improvements

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are exactly, but `^https:\/\/www.indiegogo.com\/explore\/[a-z\-&_=]+$` matches the sample URL I used too. The only issue is it doesn't require the URL to contain `&project_timing=` or `&tags=&sort=trending`. I'm not sure if that's important to you.

Comment: If the beginning and end is all you care about `^https:\/\/www.indiegogo.com\/explore\/[a-z\-&_=]+&tags=&sort=trending$` works too.

Comment: that format of the urls i listed in my questions is specific to the way in which the links i want are structured. when you start messing with the other stuff, there's a good chance i may end up matching stuff i don't want to :/