# python regex how to add patterns together with the pipe operand |

Tags: python, regex, string

I am dealing with strings in python and have to solve the following problem.

how to get rid of a first part of a string up to the FIRST appearance of a particular substring.

Example: give me the text including and after the FIRST APPEARANCE of xx.  or XX.

```
text = 'this is another text XX. appel YY. banana xx. orange'
result = re.search(r"(?:xx\.|XX\.)(.*)",text).group(1) 
result
```

So far so good.

Now imaging a lot more cases have to be treated.
like YYY. yyy. etc

for organising purposes I would like to be able to code it in the following way:
(pseudo code, it does not work)

```
pattern1 = r'xx\.|XX\.'
pattern2 = r'yy\.|YY\.'
pattern3 = r'whatever1\.|whatever2\.|whatever3'
total_pattern = r'(?:' + '|' + pattern1 + '|' + pattern2 + '|' + pattern3 ..
```

Imagine in every of the patterns there will be a multiple set of options
I want to avoid to have a large multiline piece of code that will be unreadable for any other colleague reviewing the code. Every of the pattern relates to a different issue.

total_pattern results in:
'(?:|xx\.|XX\.|yy\.|YY\.|whatever1\.|whatever2\.|whatever3'

Does not matter if I use the r' in front of the pattern variables or not.

ultimately what I want to do is:

```
total_pattern = total_pattern + '(.*)'
result = re.search(total_pattern,text).group(1) 
result
```

the double \ messes up the pattern and the result is not as expected since there is no matches.

expected output:

```
XX. appel YY. banana xx. orange
```

EDIT: The questions is not about getting the best regex (more compressed or whatever, its simply about adding patterns OUTSIDE the re.search regex method

EDIT2: This solution does not work:
[Pythonic way to concatenate regex objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102814/pythonic-way-to-concatenate-regex-objects)
due to the use of \ inside the patterns

Comment: Use raw strings r"like this"` to solve your issues with backslashes. And if you use case-insensitive matching (flag `re.I`) you might not need to use so many `|`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```py
import re

patterns = [
    "XX.", "xx.",  # the xx
    "YY.", "yy.",  # the yy
    "whatever1.", "whatever2.", "whatever3",  # the whatevers
]
total_pattern = re.compile("((?:" + "|".join(map(re.escape, patterns)) + ").*)")


the_text = "this is another text XX. appel YY. banana xx. orange"
print(total_pattern.search(the_text).group(1))
```

Prints:

```
XX. appel YY. banana xx. orange
```

It uses [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) so you don't need to manually escape any regex-special characters from your patterns with backslashes.
Also, since you want the capturing group to include your pattern, I changed the the brackets so the non-capturing group is within the capturing group.
That is the whole match, though, so you could just as well get rid of the capturing group and use group 0, which is always the whole matching part.

```py
import re

patterns = [
    "XX.", "xx.",  # the xx
    "YY.", "yy.",  # the yy
    "whatever1.", "whatever2.", "whatever3",  # the whatevers
]
total_pattern = re.compile("(?:" + "|".join(map(re.escape, patterns)) + ").*")


the_text = "this is another text XX. appel YY. banana xx. orange"
print(total_pattern.search(the_text).group(0))
```

Same result.

However, there's no reason why it shouldn't also work like this:

```py
import re

patterns = [
    r"XX\.|xx\.",  # the xx'es
    r"YY\.|yy\.",  # the yy'es
    r"whatever1\.|whatever2\.|whatever3",  # the whatevers
]
total_pattern = re.compile("(?:" + "|".join(patterns) + ").*")


the_text = "this is another text XX. appel YY. banana xx. orange"
print(total_pattern.search(the_text).group(0))
```

So I wonder, maybe the way you create `total_pattern` doesn't work?